# how can I sync the database of SMF and Joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5, smf

I have a Joomla and SMF forum.., I want to sync the data.., when the a user from joomla will register, automatically, it is also register in the SMF forum..,

tnx for the replies.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an SMF/Joomla bridge - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum-bridges/11442

Comment: Is there any free plugins/bridge for free?..,

tnx for the reply

Comment: You can try JFusion, but they do not support SMF2.0 yet, only 1.1.8. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-bridges/3723